# generating Stubs with wsimport from WSDL over https

Tags: java, web-services, https, jboss, jax-ws

I'm trying to generate my client stub with the jax-ws wsimport.
My Web Service is running on Jboss 7.1.1, but all Request go to Apache over https, which just rewriting the Url from https to http and editing the port.

My wsimport looks like this:

```
wsimport -keep https:// server/webservice?wsdl
```

My publishing adress:

```
http://server :8099/webservice
```

If i go direct to Jboss all is fine, but if i try to go over apache with https im getting following exception:

```
[ERROR] White spaces are requieed between publicId and systemId.
 line 1 of https: //server/webservice?wsdl
[ERROR] White spaces are requieed between publicId and systemId.
 Failed to read the WSDL document: https://...., because 1)could not find the document; /2)the document could not be read; /3 the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.
[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
At leadt one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
    Failed to parse the wsdl
```

Is there mabe any configuration i have to do if i go over https?